# Setting up an email only domain

Tags: web-hosting, domains, email

I want to set up an email address with a custom domain. What would be the best way to do this ?

My only real requirement is the email address, the service may be hosted or just email forwarding.

Is it possible to just buy the domain and use some other services to set up the email ?

**P.S:** A cost estimate and references to any how-to's would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest/cheapest way is to buy the domain with a company that allows you full access to the domain's DNS settings and then use a service like [google apps standard edition](https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/standard/new3) to run your email through.

Once you sign-up for the service, google walk you through the changes, and there is plenty of support available here or on google groups.

The only cost in this case would be the domain so $6 - $8 USD.

The http end can just be parked or ignored.

**To answer the comment below regarding DNS**

It is required for the ISP to be able to modify DNS, but how much control YOU have varies from provider to provider, so check what kind of DNS records you're allowed to change YOURSELF before buying.

In this specific case you'd need to be able to change your domain's MX records at a minimum, and possibly the CNAME and A records depending on which options you decide to setup.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'full access to the domain's DNS setting' ? Isn't that access required in any case ?

Comment: @SaadFarooq I've updated the answer to include more information.